# Finding records based on no returned records from a related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Dealing with two tables in Postgres: Members and Memberships. Memberships have an end_date column that can be NULL if the membership is still running. As soon as it has ended, or the end date is known (can be the future) the field gets populated with the date.

Now I would like to find all members that have no active membership at the moment (or: only memberships with end_dates set and in the past or 0 memberships). Members can have more than 1 membership obviously.

I am doing this in a Rails (3.2) project and would like to be able to use ActiveRecord if possible, but if necessary straight SQL will do (although I know ActiveRecord better).

I have tried to find all sorts of things with subqueries, but I cannot find a way to select the rows where a the count of specific rows in a related table is 0.

I have been googling for quite a while now, but have run out of ideas about how to search. Most answers deal with finding records that do match criteria and I feel I wan't those that do not match. Maybe it is a newbie question or I am targeting it wrong. In that case: please enlighten me, I am kinda just beginning.

Based on the partial answer by Jakub I have tried a lot more. At the moment I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  m.id, m.first_name, m.last_name, COUNT (ms.id) AS n_memberships
FROM 
  members AS m
LEFT JOIN memberships AS ms
ON m.id = ms.member_id
GROUP BY m.id, ms.end_date
HAVING (max(ms.end_date) < now() AND NOT COUNT(ms.end_date = NULL) > 0) OR COUNT(ms.id) = 0;
```

This returns all members that have no membership at all (no past and no current). Based on the last part of the HAVING clause (the OR ... part).
I do however expect members with expired memberships and no current memberships to be returned, too, because max(ms.end_date) will return a value less than now and there will be no memberships without a given end date. This does not happen though, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an `OUTER JOIN`. The SQL code to find members with no memberships is:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN memberships AS s
   ON m.id=s.member_id
WHERE s.id IS NULL;
```

The full query:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN memberships AS s
   ON m.id=s.member_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING max(s.end_date)<now() OR max(s.end_date) IS NULL
```

Comment: It is getting fairly close, but not complete yet. If I omit the "OR...." section I will find members with memberships that have ended, but if they added a new membership they will still come forward, although they are member again.

Comment: Should have added this: Besides, s.end_date IS NULL will be true for anyone in a current membership, as any running membership will not have an end date to it. I am trying to get a count put in somewhere, but I can't get it to work. If the count of memberships for a m.id is 0 or all s's for an m.id have 'end_date <now()' they comply.